# Accessing Bluetooth Phone Operations and Settings Programmatically, C#

Tags: java, c#, windows, bluetooth, hfp

I need to access Bluetooth Phone Operations and setting services , as offered in Windows7, through a c# application. I want to achieve exactly same functionalities, like connect, disconnect, call, reject/receive, using computer as headset/speakerphone etc.

I don't have much of a knowledge about these services (BT, HFP, HSP). So any help would be really appreciated regarding concepts.

PS: I want to accomplish this .Net (C#), but Java is fine too!